# docker-elk , elk installation issues memory

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have retrieved elk with the following command:

docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.1.1

Then
I have also run this on ec2
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

This is the content of docker-compose file 
docker-compose.yml:

version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.1.1
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.1.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge

but i keep on having this error with the compose up command

docker-compose up

```
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000e5330000, 449642496, 0) failed; error='Out of memory' (errno=12)
```

elasticsearch2_1  | #
elasticsearch2_1  | # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
elasticsearch2_1  | # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 449642496 bytes for committing reserved memory.
elasticsearch2_1  | # An error report file with more information is saved as:
elasticsearch2_1  | # /usr/share/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid1.log
ec2user_elasticsearch2_1 exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS)?

It's strange because your ECS-compose file should not work: mem_limit is **in bytes**.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html

```
version: '2'
services:
    elasticsearch1:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.1.1
        container_name: elasticsearch1
        environment:
            - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms500m -Xmx500m
        mem_limit: 524288000
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
            nofile:
                soft: 65536
                hard: 65536
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
```

Did you "sudo" this command?

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Why your settings talk about "elasticsearch1" and your logs "elasticsearch2_1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Build docker using below GitHub repository and upload it in AWS ECR,

https://github.com/nxtcloud-io/elk

The sample task definition for ECS is provided in the 
    https://github.com/nxtcloud-io/elk/blob/master/ecs/task-defination.json

I recommend using at least 2 GB RAM for your container